# How to configure default application.properties via e.g. custom starter?

Tags: spring-boot

To ease internal development I'm thinking of developing a thin layer / customer starter for Spring Boot.
This custom starter just depends on some boot starters and some other dependencies we need (both external and internal).

Anyway, next step I want to do is that this custom starter includes an application.properties configuration with default setting we want to apply in our projects.
And I would like this configuration file to be picked up automatically without referring to it explicitly. Off course it should be possible to override the properties in the actual projects.

Does Boot already offer something to this easily?

Note: I already have 'Custom'Application extending Boot's SpringApplication; so if I can configure it this way would be no problem.

Comment: It should be possible to add multiple `application.properties` as long as they are on the default locations. Else you can provide a default and use an external `application.properties` file to override the properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot looks for properties using a [specific order](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config):

1. Command line arguments
2. Java System properties (`System.getProperties()`)
3. OS environment variables
4. JNDI attributes from `java:comp/env`
5. A `RandomValuePropertySource` that only has properties in `random.*`
6. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (`application.properties` including YAML     and profile variants)
7. Application properties packaged inside your jar (`application.properties` including YAML and profile variants)
8. `@PropertySource` annotations on your `@Configuration` classes
9. Default properties (specified using `SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties`)

To give the projects using your custom starter the most flexibility in how to override the defaults, you should use a mechanism that's as near to the end of the above list as possible.
Given that you already have your own subclass of `SpringApplication`, I would use [`SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties(Properties)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.7.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#setDefaultProperties(java.util.Properties)) from within that subclass.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I should have checked the docs better :-(. 8 or 9 is indeed  exactly what I need.